# Scroll to bottom of div every X seconds

Tags: javascript, scroll, intervals

Here's my code:

```
function scrollFix() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat_box_scroll_region");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}

setTimeout(scrollFix(), 500);
```

Do you see anything wrong? With chrome's built in console I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
```

and then nothing happens. I should point out that the content of the element will expand every other second or so, if that matters.

EDIT: I want to be able to bookmark this javascript code and just run it once and get it working...

Comment: You should pass a function reference to `setTimeout`. Passing `scrollFix()` means you're calling it and passing the return value to `setTimeout`. The fix: `setTimeout(scrollFix, 500);`

Answer (score 1):

What that error is telling you is that it can't find the element with the id "chat_box_scroll_region". This might happen if you've put this code you've provided in the page ABOVE where you define the "chat_box_scroll_region" element. You'll want to have it call the function once the page is fully loaded.

Also, if you want it to constantly try to scroll down, you'll need to tell the function to call itself again.

```
function scrollFix() {   
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat_box_scroll_region");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
  setTimeout("scrollFix();", 500);
}
window.onload = function() { scrollFix(); }
```

Comment: I guessed the message meant that. I'm not a javascript pro, but if a element is added AFTER the page has loaded, wont i have to use live() or something similar? (live() is included in jQuery, so there should be a way to do it in plain javascript...), or am i wrong? Either way i found a better way of doing it, but i still have that problem, that i can't "find" the element, even though it's there. My new solution is to set the scrollTop to a value like 9999, by doing that i only need to run the code once.

Comment: Yes, you'd use live() in this instance. I wasn't sure if you were using jQuery or not.

Comment: Well it's not my site, but the site i'm gonna use it for does not use jQuery. Is there a plain javascript way of doing it?

Comment: The function in my original reply should do it.

Comment: But it doesn't. I give up! :/

Comment: No, i don't give up! I just looked through the source of the site now and found out that it's actually placed within an <iframe>, that's why i can't find the element! Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null` means that `document.getElementById("chat_box_scroll_region");` did not locate an element with that ID. Use Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools to verify that your div has exactly that ID.

Comment: I just looked through the source of the site now and found out that it's actually placed within an <iframe>, that's why i can't find the element! Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are reporting indicates that objDiv == null, which means that at the time of execution, no element named "chat_box_scroll_region" exists in your document.

If your intention is to run scrollFix() after 500ms timeout, you will want to enclose the call in quotes, as in `setTimeout("scrollFix()", 500)`.  Otherwise, scrollFix will simply be called immediately and its return value will be passed into setTimeout.

A better option may in fact be to execute this code in the body onload handler.  *i.e.*, in your HTML document, affix an attribute like `onload='javascript:scrollFix()'` to the `body` tag.

Even further, since I'm assuming you want to execute this function regularly (though there are perhaps better ways to deal with a scrolling chatbox), you will also want to call `setTimeout("scrollFix()", 500)` at the end of your scrollFix() function.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there are better ways of doing it. Another way that i found is to just set scrollTop to a high value like 9999, that way i only have to run the code once. Might not be the best way, but it's much better. The problem still persists though, that i can't "find" the element even though it's there (and yes, it's spelled right!). The element might be added after loading time, if i'm not wrong, i need to re-load the HTML through javascript or something like that. (not sure what it's called, i believe there's a function in jQuery called live() that does that, not sure though..).